# Can't remove numbers from my divs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I'm building a game in JavaScript, with a basic gird layout built-in JavaScript, and cannot remove the numbers (1, 2, 3, 4...) from the top left of the grid (image below).

I think they were generated as part of my JavaScript, however, I cannot remove them. I've tried looking at my CSS, and cannot find it anywhere. Can anybody help?

[image]

JavaScript

```
function init() {

      // DOM Elements
      const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
      const cells = []
      let linkPosition = 0
    
      // Grid Values
      const width = 10
      const cellCount = width * width
    
      // Function
      function createGrid() {
        for (let i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
          const cell = document.createElement('div')
          cells.push(cell)
          cell.innerHTML = i
          grid.appendChild(cell)
        }
        cells[linkPosition].classList.add('link')
      }
      createGrid()
    
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
```

CSS

```
/* Misc */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F9F9F3;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

span {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}



/* Heading Wrapper */

.heading-wrapper {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.heading img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 300px;
}

/* Controls Wrapper */

.controls-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Grid Layout */

.grid-wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid {
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  background-image: url('../assets/background-image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.grid div {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
}

.grid div.link {
  background-image: url('../assets/link.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: remove `cell.innerHTML = i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this function on your JavaScript, I don't get it - why you need the line where `cell.innerHTML = i` ? Do you need for some reason? If not, I think if just remove this line will do the job.

```
// Function
function createGrid() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cellCount; i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement('div')
        cells.push(cell)
        cell.innerHTML = i // This line maybe remove it if not necessary in other function 
        grid.appendChild(cell)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove this line:

```
cell.innerHTML = i
```